# logged in function PassportJS always return 0

Tags: node.js, angular, express, passport.js, passport-local

I have implements passportJS in my application the login function work good but when I try to get the current connected user with (req.isAuthenticated()) it always return "0"

here is my page : auth.js

```
    /* Passport - Sessions - Cookies Dependecies */
    var passport = require('passport');
    var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(localStrategy));
    passport.serializeUser(serializeUser);
    passport.deserializeUser(deserializeUser);
    /* End dependecies */


    /* Routing */
    router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), login);
    router.get('/loggedin', loggedin);


    var auth = authorized;

    /* Functions */
    function localStrategy(username, password, done) {
        User
            .findOne({ email: username })
            .then(
                function (user) {
                    if (user) {
                        var isValid = user.comparePassword(password);
                        if (isValid) {
                            return done(null, user);
                        } else {
                            return done(null, false);
                        }
                    } else {
                        return done(null, false);
                    }
                },
                function (err) {
                    if (err) { return done(err); }
                }
            );
    }

    function login(req, res) {
        return res.json(req.user);
    }
    function logout(req, res) {
        req.logOut();
        res.send(200);
    }
    function loggedin(req, res) {
        res.send(req.isAuthenticated() ? req.user : '0');
    }


    function authorized(req, res, next) {
        if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
            res.send(401);
        } else {
            next();
        }
    };
    /** Serialize & Deserialize Cookies **/
    function serializeUser(user, done) {
        done(null, user);
    }

    function deserializeUser(id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    };
module.exports = router;
```

and here is my server.js

```
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'mySecretKey',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
// END passportJS

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    next();
});
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
```

Could any one please help in getting the current connected user from my separed angular4 applications running in heroku

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `serializeUser` function. What you pass to the `done()` call inside this function, is what you'll get back as argument in `deserializeUser`.

In your case, you're passing the entire user object to `done` in `serializeUser`, but expect only the `id` in `deserializeUser`.

So change your serializeUser function to this:

```
function serializeUser(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    }
```

This will ensure only id is serialized, which will be the same you'll get in deserialize.

Comment: Thank you for you answer I tried this with user.id and user._id in the serializeUser function and it doesn't work! 
I believe that user is not stored in cookies or session!
Do you have any idea to check this?

Comment: @NourJadlaoui Add a console log into both functions and see what you get